# Why is it creating same array for both the div's

Tags: jquery

could anybody please tell me why its creating the same array (toppings) for both the div's of ordersdiv ul .

Here in my case the Strawberry doesn't have any elements under Topping-details class .

But its creating the same values for both of them

Here in my case the Strawberry  doesn't have any elements under Topping-details , Chocolate has data under Topping-details  , but the same array is being created for both the div's .

This is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RD3HZ/5/

This is the logic i am following currently

```
$.each($('#ordersdiv ul'), function (i, elem) {
    name = $(elem).find("label").text();
    toppings = [];
    $('#ordersdiv .Topping-details .tdHeading').each(function () {
        values = [];
        $(this).parent().find('.tpActive').each(function () {
            values.push($(this).text());
        });
        toppings.push({
            'name': $(this).text(),
                'value': values
        });
    });
    products.push({
        'name': name,
            'toppings': toppings
    });
});
```

I am expecting output should be

```
[
    {
        "name": "Strawberry",
        "toppings": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Chocolate",
        "toppings": [
            {
                "name": "Chocolate0",
                "value": [
                    "Honey Sauce  10 ML",
                    "Caramel Sauce  10 ML"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Chocolate1",
                "value": [
                    "Honey with Carmel  10 ML"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Could anybody please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 `ul`s in your HTML code, in each loop, the `$('#ordersdiv .Topping-details .tdHeading')` returns the same collection of elements. Hence your problem. You have to select the `.tdHeading` ***in relation with*** the current `ul` element. I think your HTML code should be reorganized to make this relation better. However with the current HTML code, you can change the `.tdHeading` selecting code from:

```
$('#ordersdiv .Topping-details .tdHeading')
```

to this:

```
$(this).closest('.product-item').next('.Topping-details').find('.tdHeading')
```

### [Updated demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/RD3HZ/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to get your expected output... just check

```
var name;
var values = [];
var toppings = [];
var products = [];
$.each($('#ordersdiv ul'), function (i, elem) {
    name = $(elem).find("label").text();
    toppings = [];

    $('.Topping-details .tdHeading',$(elem).parent().parent()).each(function () {
        values = [];
        val = $(this).text();
        $(this).parent().find('.tpActive').each(function () {

                values.push($(this).text());
        });
        if(val.indexOf(name)> -1)
        toppings.push({
            'name': $(this).text(),
                'value': values
        });
    });
    products.push({
        'name': name,
            'toppings': toppings
    });
});

alert(JSON.stringify(products));
```

check at fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kka284556/RD3HZ/8/